# Noise disturbance when generating sine audio wave in python

Tags: python, audio

I have written a small piece of python code (most of which i copied from SO itself) which works fine if my duration is 0.1 but if my duration is 0.05 i hear some clicks in the sound. Not sure why this is happening.

I need to play a much higher number of frequencies with a lower duration but the sound in that case is completely messed up. Attaching code below:

```
import numpy as np
import sounddevice as sd

def playArray(pts, time):

    samplerate = 44100.0
    sd.default.samplerate = samplerate
    volume = 10000
    count = len(pts)

    samples = np.arange(samplerate * time ) / samplerate

    wave = []
    for freq in pts:
        wavelet = volume * np.sin( 2 * np.pi * freq * samples)
        wave = np.concatenate([wave, wavelet])

    wav_wave = np.array(wave, dtype=np.int16)
    sd.play(wav_wave, blocking=True)

pts = np.arange(300, 1500, 10)
playArray(pts, 0.1)
```

Comment: You should plot your wave forms, then you'll quickly see what's wrong. You are concatenating sine tones, completely ignoring their phases. That's bound to go wrong. Even if you would align the phases, you might still get audible artifacts if you have rapid changes in frequency. If you need a sine sweep, you can try [scipy.signal.chirp()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.chirp.html). There are also some other libraries that provide similar signals.

Comment: Is your audio duration 0.1 minutes or 0.1 seconds?

Comment: @Anil_M its seconds

Comment: @SagarSodah: Pls. Check my answer for easy way to to generate milliseconds length sine Tones

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Matthias comment I changed my code to incorporate phase into the sampling.

> Here is the updated code:

```
import numpy as np
import sounddevice as sd
import math

def playArray(pts, time):

    samplerate = 44100.0
    sd.default.samplerate = samplerate
    volume = 10000
    total = len(pts)
    count = 0
    phase = 0.0
    samples = np.zeros(math.ceil(samplerate * time  * total), dtype = np.float)

    for i, val in enumerate(samples):
        freq = pts[count]
        freqRads = 2 * np.pi * freq / samplerate
        phase = phase + freqRads
        sampleValue = volume * np.sin(phase)
        samples[i] = sampleValue
        if ( i >  0 and i % (samplerate * time) == 0):
            count = count + 1

    wav_wave = np.array(samples, dtype=np.int16)
    sd.play(wav_wave, blocking=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to create a sine tone of short duration , you may want to look at [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown).

You can use `pydub.generators` module that has classes to create different waveforms such as `sine` , `square`, `pulse`, `sawtooth` etc. and with least amount of code.

And you can create waveforms down to few milliseconds duration.

Here is a working example that creates sine wave for a duration of 0.05 sec(50 millisec).

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.generators import Sine
from pydub.playback import play

frequency = 2000 #in Hz

#create sine wave of given freq
sine_wave = Sine(frequency, sample_rate=44100, bit_depth=16)

#Convert waveform to audio_segment for playback and export
#duation is in millisec
sine_segment = sine_wave.to_audio_segment(duration=50.0) 

#Play audio segment
play(sine_segment)

#save / export audio_segment
sine_segment.export("out_sine.wav", format="wav")
```

Length of audio segment can be found using

```
#Duration in seconds
>>> sine_segment.duration_seconds
0.05

#Duration in milliseconds
>>> len(sine_segment)
50
>>>
```

More on generator module [here](http://pydoc.net/Python/pydub/0.9.4/pydub.generators/).
Hope this helps.